# How to get the row for the current date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Pretend today 2022-10-24

case 1

| id | productCode | version | startDate | endDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | 1 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-10-28 |
| 2 | AAA | 2 | 2022-10-29 | NULL |

case 1 depend on table above, I want to return only 1 row at id 1, why cause today 2022-10-24 still between startDate and endDate

case 2

| id | productCode | version | startDate | endDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | 1 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-10-28 |
| 2 | AAA | 2 | 2022-10-01 | NULL |

case 2 depends on table above. I want to return only 1 row at id 2. Why cause when startDate has the same value between id 1 & 2, so choose endDate with NULL value.

I am still confused about how to implement this with query.
I want to make for one query logic. When running query so when use case 1 return id 1 and when I use for case 2 return id 2.

Comment: Seems like you want a `BETWEEN` with a [top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group).

Comment: For a productCode, do you have only two versions (1 & 2)?

Comment: @ahmed yes for now still 2 version. my question above, i want to make one query logic for case 1 and case 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mention in the comments, seems you just need some simple `>=` and `<(=)` logic (while handling `NULL`s) and a "Top 1 per group":

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT id,
           productCode,
           version,
           startDate,
           endDate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY productCode ORDER BY Version DESC) AS RN --Guessed the required partition and order clauses
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    WHERE startDate <= CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
      AND (endDate >= CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) OR endDate IS NULL))
SELECT id,
       productCode,
       version,
       startDate,
       endDate
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```